# How can I make require_once fetch a file from the directory above?

Tags: php, apache, pear, require-once

I'm trying to set up a site of which I was not the original owner, on a new server - In Apache2, the document root has been set to /var/www/html, which is where the index.php that I want to be the default 'homepage' is located.

There are a number of files in other directories in www. For an example, /common/cachelite/Lite.php can also be found in /var/www.

The php in index.php references this using require_once, like below:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('Display_errors','On');
require_once('../common/cachelite/Lite.php');
```

But throws the following error, which I have taken from my Apache2 error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../common/cachelite/Lite.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

The file itself is definitely there, so can anybody shed some light on this issue for me? What's going on?

Comment: `require`/`include` are NOT bound by the webserver's document root. That's a concept that exists only in the webserver. PHP sees only the filesystem, and can access any file/directory on it that its containing user ID has access to.

Comment: I thought as much, but then the fact I can't seem to require this file made me question my own knowledge...

Comment: plunk yourself in a shell open to the same directory as your php script. then figure out what the `../whatever` path should be to get from where your script is to where the included file is. That'll be the path you need inside PHP.

Comment: Yeah but that's .. (up one directory), then into /common/cachelite/Lite.php, so '../common/cachelite/Lite.php', which is exactly what I have. It's not working for some reason... I can nano into the file from the index.php directory by doing nano ../common/cachelite/Lite.php, or cd there using that path... Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: said failed opening, not "no such file", so probably it's a permissions issue. make sure that the account you're running the script as has the writes to both the folders AND the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

I have run in to this problem a few times and always fix it like so.

```
$file = dirname(dirname(__file__));
require_once($file ."/common/cachelite/Lite.php");
```

To narrow it down further.

try this
if doing it on the web server and not command line add <pre></pre> tags.

```
echo __file__ . "\n";
echo dirname(__file__). "\n";
echo dirname(dirname(__file__)). "\n";
```

My next thought is, file permissions or misspelled words.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix this for me I'm afraid, same error as before (with the line number nudged up to 5, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to something like

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/cachelite/Lite.php');
```

or you can also follow this way:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/common/cachelite/Lite.php');
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I end up with `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/common/cachelite/Lite.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4`

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the files that you are trying to require/include. If they can't be read by the accessing/web user then that would explain the error that you are encountering.