# require_once not working on live server

Tags: php, wordpress, pear

I have a situation where a php line is working fine on localhost but not on live server, even if I have the same file and folder structure.

```
require_once '/../Renderer.php';
```

The error I am getting on live server is:

> Warning: require_once(/../Renderer.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home2/attafsir/public_html/balaghatoalquran/production/wp-content/themes/twentyten/Text/Diff/Renderer/unified.php
>   on line 19
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/../Renderer.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home2/attafsir/public_html/balaghatoalquran/production/wp-content/themes/twentyten/Text/Diff/Renderer/unified.php
>   on line 19

I have spend a lot of time trying to figure out what could be the reasons behind such behaviour, but to no avail, your help is appreciated.

PS: I have verified with my host if PEAR is installed and configured in php.ini, and they confirm it to me. (since the code is using PEAR package)

**Solution:**
The solution is the accepted answer, but I want to notice though that the problem on live server is resolved but broke the functionning on localhost. This is a temporary solution since the best thing is to have the same code on local and live server. I will be back to post a full solution when I find it. your suggestion are always welcome.

Comment: This means the file does not exists. Check what is the actual name of the file `renderer.php` or `Renderer.php` since unix machines are case sensitive

Comment: @Guns, the file name is `Renderer.php`. thank you for the remark, unfortunately this doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: You are not using the proper file location.

Comment: It could also have to do with \ in windows and / in linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` is the root of the file-system and then you try to go up one level with `..`. That does not exist so you get an error.

Are you sure you do not want a relative path?

If you want it to be relative to the root of the web-server (which is not the root of the file-system unless there is something very wrong), use something like:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../Renderer.php'
```

Comment: I inspired from your answer to find the solution (which unfortunately break the functionnnig on localhost).

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces It shouldn't, if your local web-server is correctly set up, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should give you the root folder of your web-site.

Comment: what are you saying is logical, but I still dont understand why I should put different lines of code in the same file while passing from localhost to live.this behavior never appeared in the whole website except for `require_once`.thank you for your time

Comment: If you were using html links, / is your document root. in php, it is the filesystem root. Try changing to include_once, include, or require, you will still have the same issue.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Could be a directory-separator issue between windows and linux, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178263/make-a-path-work-both-on-linux-and-windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966889/how-can-i-make-require-once-fetch-a-file-from-the-directory-above?rq=1

Mark B says it well: `"require/include are NOT bound by the webserver's document root. That's a concept that exists only in the webserver. PHP sees only the filesystem, and can access any file/directory on it that its containing user ID has access to."`

Answer (score 1):

Try just:

```
require_once '../Renderer.php';
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately, this doesnt resolve the problem

Comment: Hmmm, and you can verify `Renderer.php` is here: `/home2/attafsir/public_html/balaghatoalquran/production/wp-content/themes/twentyten/Text/Diff/Renderer.php` ?

Comment: according to my file manager in hosting account, the location of file is exact and the file exists there

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces In a hosting account / is the root of your account, your files may be in public_html httpdocs etc. Who do you use for hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '/../Renderer.php'. It's either '../' which refers to one folder up or '/' which refers to root directory.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working. only require_once '/../Renderer.php'; that works but only on localhost

Comment: You might have windows based localhost. Also server configurations are different. Check the path of the file.

Comment: yes, i agree with you, this is logically the cause (windows on localhost and Linux on live server)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first slash and try either:

```
require_once '../Renderer.php';
```

Or

```
require_once '../../Renderer.php';
```

Which one works depends on your file structure.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working. only `require_once '/../Renderer.php';` that works but only on localhost

Answer (score 0):

require_once **DRI** . '/../Renderer.php';

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it understandable.

Answer (score -1):

I am faceing same problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5owZj.png)Change your Current version PHP to PHP 5.3